# How to get bitset BLOBs from Mysql select ID queries?

Tags: mysql, blob, bitset

It would be absolutely great if the following thing was possible:

Let's say I've got a 'document' mysql table, with a document 'id' and a few other columns:

```
CREATE TABLE document(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ....);
```

There can be quite a lot of document, but let's say that for now I've got only 2 millions.

I'd like to get the result of this query in my programming language space quickly:

```
SELECT id FROM document WHERE ... whatever ...;
```

The clause 'whatever' is potentially empty, so the set can contain the id's of all documents.

So my question is: is there a way to get the result of this query as bit vector BLOB of size 2 million bits (~ 250k of data) instead of potentially 2 millions of stringified numbers ( ~ 14Mo .. not great).

Extra kudos for blob compression in case of sparse sets :)

Comment: Hmm... does this really belong in the database layer?  The only way I can think of doing it in MySQL is to write a [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/adding-udf.html) that initialises then updates a `BLOB` value during group aggregation; [`BIT_OR(1<<id)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or) would have done the trick, if it wasn't limited to 64-bit precision.

Comment: Yeah I guess that if there's no way of doing it natively, a new function with the signature BLOB f(id_query , id_name, max_id) would do the job. I guess I'll have to blow the dust from my C compiler :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While performance will be horrendous, this stored procedure will give you the result you requested:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ex12688666(whatever TEXT)
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
COMMENT ''
proc: BEGIN
    DECLARE not_found   BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE max         BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE len         BIGINT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE i           BIGINT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE pos         BIGINT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE result      LONGBLOB DEFAULT '';

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT id FROM ids WHERE id RLIKE whatever ORDER BY id;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET not_found = TRUE;

    SELECT MAX(id) INTO max FROM ids;

    IF (max > 0) THEN
        SET len = FLOOR((max + 7) / 8);
        SET result = REPEAT("\0", len);

        OPEN cur1;

        loop1: LOOP
            FETCH cur1 INTO i;
            IF not_found THEN
                LEAVE loop1;
            END IF;

            SET pos = FLOOR(i / 8) + 1;
            SET result = CONCAT(
                SUBSTRING(result, 1, pos - 1), 
                CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(result, pos, 1)) | (1 << (i MOD 8))), 
                SUBSTRING(result, pos + 1)
            );
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE cur1;
    END IF;

    SELECT HEX(result) AS result;
END;
```

We're returning `HEX(result)` for illustrative purposes. In practice, one could replace

```
SELECT HEX(result) AS result;
```

with simply

```
SELECT result;
```

or if you want zlib compression of the result:

```
SELECT COMPRESS(result) AS result;
```

which should get the extra kudos you mentioned.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f5c0/1 for an interactive demo.